# How do I apply events to a dynamically created picturebox?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I wrote the code below so that I can drag and drop a picturebox. And it works fine. However, I'm making an application which may have like 100 different pictureboxes. Is there a way to apply the events in my code to every single picturebox there is?

Also the 100 is not a pre-defined amount. Because I'll be making a toolbox in my application from where users can drag images (pictureboxes) onto the form.

```
    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        dragging = true;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        if (dragging) {
            dragging = false;
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        if (dragging) {
            pictureBox1.Left = Cursor.Position.X - pictureBox1.Width;
            pictureBox1.Top = Cursor.Position.Y - pictureBox1.Height;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Cast the sender to the PictureBox type.

Comment: ^---- (continued from @LarsTech) and register with event registration dynamically from code instead of the designer using += syntax.

Comment: this isn't exactly a duplicate of that link. somewhere in your code you will be creating a bunch of picture boxes in code, this is where you add event handlers for MouseDown, MouseUp, and MouseMove to each pictureBox.  while(true){
  PictureBox pictureBox = new PictureBox();
pictureBox.MouseDown += new RoutedEventHandler(pictureBox_MouseDown);
pictureBox.MouseUp += new RoutedEventHandler(pictureBox_MouseUp);
pictureBox.MouseMove += new RoutedEventHandler(pictureBox_MouseMove);
}

the link provided as a "duplicate" does not cover dynamic creation of a pictureBox or registering an event

Comment: @user3164339 `the link provided as a "duplicate" does not cover dynamic creation of a pictureBox or registering an event`.  Between the question and the answer, yes it does.